# Double Range Slider - Handling when the Minimum/Maximum value overlaps the other

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

I'm building a range slider in Svelte where users can select a minimum and maximum value. The slider consists of two overlapping sliders that create a double range.

My implementation is as follows:

```
<script>
  const max = 300;
  let curMin = 0;
  let curMax = max;

  $: leftPercent = (curMin / max) * 100;
  $: rightPercent = ((max - curMax) / max) * 100;
  $: {
    if (curMax <= curMin) curMax = curMin + 10;
  }
  $: {
    if (curMin >= curMax) curMin = curMax - 10;
  }
</script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="progress" style="left:{leftPercent}%; right:{rightPercent}%" />
</div>
<div class="range-input">
  <input type="range" class="range-min" min="0" {max} bind:value={curMin} step="10" />
  <input type="range" class="range-max" min="0" {max} bind:value={curMax} step="10" />
</div>
```

The implementation works properly when the maximum value exceeds the minimum value. The maximum slider drags the minimum one, both are increasing by 10. But not when the minimum value exceeds the maximum value. In this case, the sliders just overlap and freeze.

To fix this, I added both conditional statements together

```
 $: {
    if (curMax <= curMin) curMax = curMin + 10;
    if (curMin >= curMax) curMin = curMax - 10;
  }
```

However, this gives me a cyclic dependency error.
What can I do to either fix the cyclic dependency or maybe I should throw in a different implementation?

EDIT:
I found out that whichever conditional check is first is the one which will work. The second one will always fail.

Comment: Just a quick3-second theory: How about a different approach. Instead of attempting a calculation, simply swap the "identifier" for the points as they collide. Example: When PointA crosses PointB, it becomes PointB and PointB becomes Point A. In that moment, labels instantly swap and the user never perceives it. From the calculation perspective, the user _never_ crossed the points when dragging them, so there's no possible calculation error.

Comment: I feel so stupid now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ya, a swap somewhere is what was needed. Anyways, I worked on a range slider before. In the end, I'm using a 3rd-party component because they do fancier stuff and better support across mobile devices =P.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Thanks to [MarsAndBack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4378314/marsandback).
Just swap the values of min and max if they overlap.

```js
$: if (curMin >= curMax) {
    temp = curMin;
    curMin = curMax;
    curMax = temp;
}
```